# stretching ns analog pulses for digital conversion

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, pulse

Problem statement

in one of my design i need to stretch narrow `10 ns` pulses coming from photo diode after `TIA` stage, if i have to measure the pulse amplitude i have to stretch it at least by a factor of 100, in this search i have found a approach in which the circuit was using a capacitor after its feedback path, but i have not understood how exactly the circuit works, but when i tried to replicate it, no pulse stretch was happening, here below is the circuit and kindly suggest few modifications to the circuit or suggest an approach for the analog pulse stretch

circuit
[image]
Opamp is a high slewrate 3000V/us and high BW of  100M as `BW = 0.35/risetime` and `slewrate = 2* pi * BW * Vpp`, so for my 10ns input the opamp would do the job.

pulse output is just zero !

[image]

EDIT1:
primarily i forgot to mention that my 10ns pulses will repeat at a rate of 1Hz-50Khz, so just after some small modifications, i came with below circuit where i increased the gain and obtained pretty decent results, kindly provide your valuable comments

[image]

Results

[image]
PS: i was using TINA from TI as simulator in above case

Comment: A signal of 1nsec requires a gain bandwidth product of 1GHz, well beyond the capability of your amplifier. Note that slew rate and GBW are not directly related. The slew rate shows the fastest output available, not what the internal gain stage can handle.

Comment: @PeterSmith find the update please

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to charge a 330 pF capacitor up very quickly. Going by information from your other question this needs to be done in about 1ns. Given your pulse maybe be (say) 1V in amplitude you can work out how much current the op-amp has to supply to charge the capacitor up....

Q=CV or...

dQ/dt = C dV/dt (note that rate of change of charge equals current)

So current = 330pF * 1V per nanosecond = 330 mA

You are not going to find a fast enough op-amp that can supply this amount of current with any degree of accuracy.

You are going to be looking at something around 10pF rather than > 100 pF and you are going to need a much better op-amp as has been mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: please find the updated modification and its results

Comment: 90mA can be supplied by the op-amp to charge a 500 pF capacitor. To charge to 1V will take 5.6 ns. If you can live with this then that's fine but remember if the pulse is (say) 3 volts it'll take 3 times longer. Also remember that a simulation may not perfectly represent reality. Things like maximum output current may not be simulated in the model.

Answer (score 0):

The gain bandwidth product of the LM6172 is insufficient to handle a 1 nsec pulse; note that GBW and Slew rate are *not* directly related. See [this application note](http://www.intersil.com/data/an/an1694.pdf).

For this you could try something like the [LTC6409](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6409) or the [LMH5401](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh5401.pdf) which have a GBW sufficient for this application.

Other solutions exist, but it is highly unlikely a simple breadboard circuit would operate properly, and layout for such a circuit will require significant attention to detail.

Comment: can you please suggest the other solutions also, it would be a great help

Comment: kindly note that my pulse is 10ns not 1ns, sorry if you have misunderstood from my question

Comment: please find the updated modification and results

Comment: seems like both are FDAs, if my next stage is comparator and not ADC can i just ignore one of the outputs ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps send the pulse into a low pass filter.  50 ohms and ... 1nF or so (if I punched the numbers right.) Then amplify that signal with your slower opamp.  Or design the TIA to give longer pulses.

Comment: can you please throw some light on design of TIA to give longer pulses,seems pretty interesting, how is that possible ?

Comment: Well lower bandwidth, to make the pulses longer will also reduce the voltage.  Do you have a schematic for the TIA?  Typically increasing the feedback resistor will decrease the BW.

Comment: currently my TIA is based on OPA656 with a 12M feedback resistor for gain and 4pF feedback cap to reduce ringing effects

Comment: @kakeh, Ahh, that is a 500 MHz opamp...What's the photodiode capacitance?  I don't see anyway you are getting 1 ns pulses from that.  (Got a 'scope shot of the output?)  (12 Meg and 4 pf is ~ 50 us time constant!)  You can use an led to measure the BW.

Comment: photo diode capacitance is around 12pF, I am using the feedback capacitance 4pF in parallel with resistor Rf to reduce the parasitic effects of amplifier, cap is not placed after the opamp stage

Comment: @kakeh, So have you read about TIA amps?  For your numbers (with some opamp input C and stray.. lets call it 15 pF) with 12 Meg that is a tau of 180 us for a freq of ~1kHz... (ughh) now in the TIA you can pull that up with the opamp and get the mean of the RC freq. and the GBW of the opamp  sqrt(1kHz*500Mhz) = ~700kHz.  And you'll have tons of noise gain... hence your 4 pF in parallel with the feed back R.  You maximum pulse width is nothing like 1ns.  (have you tried simulating your TIA?)

Comment: please find the updated modification and results

Answer (score 0):

Even if the original poster has solved this problem long ago, this sort of situation does come up frequently so here is my answer, over five years later...

This is similar to problem SLAC had when designing the "Z zero Factory" in the 1980s. Very narrow pulses would arrive from beam position sensors. Their amplitudes had to be  digitized for use in steering the beams. No beam intersections, no Nobel Prize!  I spend about a year working with the EEs and techs calibrating the electronics, so I've seen this before.

The pulse were first put through a passive low pass filter, specifically a Gaussian filter that would produce an approximately Gaussian-shaped (iirc) pulse with a peak occurring several nanoseconds after the input pulse. Pure LC circuitry, with no noise, slew rates or anything else to screw with the measurements.  A sample/hold was triggered at the expected time of that peak.  The delay of the Gaussian peak relative to the original pulse gave time for the trigger circuitry to work.  The S/H used a diode bridge powered by, as I recall, four transistors arranged in an H-bridge, like a motor controller. The pulse edges of the S/H did not have to be anywhere as sharp as the edges of the original input pulse, though sharp by any ordinary standards.

We did not try to make diode-based peak detector as in the diagram you show. The forward bias of the diode would make calibration at lower beam intensities (smaller pulses) difficult. You overcome forward bias with an op amp, a standard textbook circuit perfect for such things in audio and sub-MHz applications, but for accurate measurement, forget it. Gain-bandwidth product, slew rate, stray capacitance, blah!

Good results are obtained with passive filter pre-processing, then using digitization techniques that are still quite fast but able to handle pulses on a scale of tens of nanoseconds.